# Find an anchor tag in an HTML page using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular function that retrieves the content of a folder:

```
 $http({url: dir, method: 'GET'}).then(function (results) {
                        console.log(results.data);
                        });
```

This returns an HTML page as follows:

```
    <HTML><HEAD><LINK HREF="jetty-dir.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/cs/><TITLE>Directory: /images/adImgs/</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
    <H1>Directory: /images/adImgs/</H1>
    <TABLE BORDER=0>
    <TR><TD>
    <A HREF="/images/adImgs/../">Parent Directory</A></TD><TD></TD><TD></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD><A HREF="/images/adImgs/1.jpg">1.jpg&nbsp;</A></TD><TD ALIGN=right>105236 bytes&nbsp;</TD><TD>Jan 8, 2015 3:46:10 PM</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD><A HREF="/images/adImgs/2.jpg">2.jpg&nbsp;</A></TD><TD ALIGN=right>309169 bytes&nbsp;</TD><TD>Jan 8, 2015 3:45:17 PM</TD></TR></TABLE>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

What I need is get the anchor tags in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer in pure Javascript:

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.innerHTML = response; //data retrieved from AngularJs
    var links = ul.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, you just use jquery like normal:

```
jq(htmlBlob).find('a')
```

If you're not using jquery, you have jqlite, which can find tags at the highest level. Read about jqlite here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

It would look something like:

```
angular(htmlBlob).find('a')
```

Comment: I don't use jquery... Is that a way to do it in javascript?

Comment: i'll update it, but you want angular.element(htmlBlob).find() - but you may need to know the structure of the DOM as jqlite is not as straightforward as jquery.